# Crossing your fingers

Tags: hands-fingers, superstition

Is it allowed to cross one's fingers as a sign of prayer as is the custom in Christian culture?

This question is based off other questions on this site which seem to allow one to say the phrase.

Comment: Isn't this a Xtian practice? Why should it be permitted?

Comment: In common US and European culture it is either a wish for good luck, or a way to have permission to tell a lie. There is nothing overtly religious about the phrase or activity. It may have began in pre-Christian Europe and then adopted by wider culture. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_fingers)

Comment: @shashin-ka maybe it wasn't your exposure, but having grown up in Brooklyn in an area with many Irish/Italian Catholics, the hand gesture is indeed commonly used with a "religious" connotation, i.e. to signify the cross and indicate a hope/prayer. "Hey Joe, do you think we'll win the series this year?" - Joe holds up fingers crossed. As for Wikipedia, I'd note that a) not all articles are created equal, and b) the second sentence clearly states: "Occasionally it is interpreted as an attempt to implore God for protection" see the footnote thereon.